# XSLT: transform a flat list with duplicate IDs into a hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having trouble coming up with an XSLT to recognize duplicates of a certain element, and combine/condense it to avoid duplication.

I have XML something like this:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <RelationalID>55</RelationalID>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <RelationalID>56</RelationalID>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <RelationalID>57</RelationalID>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <RelationalID>55</RelationalID>
    </item>
</items>
```

would like it to look something like:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <RelationalID>55</RelationalID>
        <RelationalID>56</RelationalID>
        <RelationalID>57</RelationalID>
    </item>
    <item>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <RelationalID>55</RelationalID>
    </item>
</items>
```

Comment: If you're using XSLT 1.0, search on muenchian grouping. If you're using XSLT 2.0, search on xsl:for-each-group. If you're still having problems, add your XSLT to your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, I don't see any real duplicates of `item`. Is it possible to have an `item` with the same `ID` and `RelationalID` as another `item`? If so, how should the XSLT handle that/what would the output look like?

Comment: Please add the XSLT you have created till now. Also, please be specific about the XSLT version you are using to transform the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard grouping problem. If you are able to use XSLT 2.0, use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="ID">
  <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/ID, current-group()/RelationalID"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, read up on Muenchian grouping.